# Count occurrences of character in string c++?

Tags: c++

Enter 1st String: ronnald macdonnald

Enter 2nd String: a

Ouput: 3

Enter 1st String: ronnald macdonnald

Enter 2nd String: nn

Ouput: 2

```
#include<iostream> 
#include<conio.h> 
using namespace std; 

int main() 
{ 
char a[100]; 
char b; 
int count = 0; 

cout << "Enter 1st String: "; 
cin.getline(a,100); 
cout << "Enter 2nd String: "; 
cin >> b; 

for(int i=0;i<strlen(a);i++) 
{ 
if(a[i] == b) 
{ 
count++; 
} 

} 
cout << "Output: " << count; 

getch(); 
return 0; 
}
```

But in my code:

Enter 1st String: ronnald macdonnald

Enter 2nd String: nn

Ouput: 4

The output should be 2

Comment: For a simple approach, you could try [`std::string::find()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find) in a loop

Comment: You forgot to ask a question. Also, have you considered debugging your program?

Comment: You say `Enter 2nd String: ` but the type you input is only a `char`. Use `std::string`.

Comment: @RaymondChen: Although there is no explicit question, I think the last few lines of the post pretty much reveal what's puzzling the OP.

Comment: From your code the answer you get is expected. You are comparing characters and 'n' appears in the first string 4 times. You are not comparing substrings.

Comment: Posted code counts characters, not substrings. "nn" is not a single character. Only first character of second line is being read and counted. As "roNNald macdoNNald" contains 4 'n' characters - the output is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is counting characters when it should be counting substrings instead, eg:

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <string>
#include <conio.h> 

int main() 
{ 
    std::string a, b; 
    int count = 0; 

    std::cout << "Enter 1st String: "; 
    std::getline(std::cin, a); 
    std::cout << "Enter 2nd String: "; 
    std::getline(std::cin, b);

    std::string::size_type i = a.find(b);
    while (i != std::string::npos)
    {
        ++count;
        i = a.find(b, i+b.length());
    } 

    std::cout << "Output: " << count; 

    getch(); 
    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: There's a minor bug, `string::find` returns a `size_t`

Comment: @w.b: fixed, though technically it returns a `std::string::size_type`, which usually maps to `size_t` (but is not required to).

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`std::count`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/count) (but as Andy Prowl noticed, only if you are checking single characters):

```
std::string str("ronnald macdonald");
std::cout << std::count(str.begin(), str.end(), 'a');  //3
```

If you are checking substrings you can use regex token iterators:

```
std::string str("Ronnald Macdonnald");

std::regex reg("nn");

std::sregex_token_iterator iter(str.begin(), str.end(), reg, 0);
std::sregex_token_iterator end;

std::vector<string> vec(iter, end);
std::cout << "Occurences: " << vec.size() << std::endl;
```

Comment: I'm afraid this won't do. The OP wants to count occurrences of substrings, not necessarily of single characters.

Answer (score 0):

You declared your second string, `b`, as `char b;`, meaning ***one single letter***.   There is no way to store the search string `"nn"` (2 letters) in a single-character location.

Because of that, you'll need to redesign some of your program.